# Facebook like button in JSF

Tags: html, facebook, restfb

I tried to generate like button using Facebook developer website. But when I tested the page the button is loaded very slow because JavaScript SDK is downloaded very slow. 
Can I use http://restfb.com/ to generate like button and use it into web page?

Comment: Here is you can check http://31stdimension.blogspot.in/2012/04/how-to-connect-facebook-using-jsfjava.html

Comment: @Subodh: OP want a like button not auth/connect button.

Comment: Are there other option for integration. For example just simple Facebook button which redirects me to Facebook page profile?

Comment: I had to place 100's of FB Like buttons on to a web site once upon a time. It slowed the web page load time down so much that it was unusable. So I turned the button into a CSS sprite map & used jQuery to bind listeners to all of the icons. When it was finished, it loaded rapidly! However, the solution wasn't well received by my client, but it worked fast! They wanted actual FB like buttons. I don't know why. They decided to scrap the idea of having 100's of FB Like buttons on a dynamically generated web page. I haven't used that library, but you could consider building your own library.

Comment: @Clomp: _“So I turned the button into a CSS sprite map & used jQuery to bind listeners to all of the icons”_ – not sure how that’s supposed to work, to achieve an actual Like being performed – but if it involves rendering the original FB Like button somehow hidden/in the background, and then using jQuery to trigger a click on them, that might easily be mistaken for click-jacking by Facebook’s algorithms (if not now, at any point in the future) – so that’s be rather risky, could be to the app id used being blocked and/or likes removed from the target in large amounts.

Comment: _“For example just simple Facebook button which redirects me to Facebook page profile?”_ – well that you can have at no cost at all, simply using a link with target=_blank and href pointing to the page in question. You can place an image/icon inside of it, up to you.

Comment: Binding listeners & click jacking are 2 separate things. Listeners wait for a user to manually click on them. The goal was to share unique data URLs with people on FB on a search results page. The FB Like button would load 10-15 assets into an iframe for each FB Like button. It would run up 100's of downloads for the same .js, .css & img files! FB's code was poorly written. My sprite map fixed problems with having 100-300+ FB Like icons on the same page, because it used 1 image, 1 CSS file, 1 JS file & then bound manual click listeners to all of the FB Like buttons, without any click jacking.

Answer (score 0):

**refer following URL for probably it help you**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button